# Change inner text selection behavior in VS Code using React JSX

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use accept a suggestion VSCode disables further autocomplete and shows as selected whatever I'm typing. I find myself constantly having to `Escape` to de-select.

[image: example behavior]

I start the autocomplete: 
[image: Start automcomplete]

Accept a suggestion: 
[image]

Whatever I type next is highlighted and autocomplete disabled: 
[image]

I have read every VS Code setting and tried anything that seems like it might influence this behavior, but nothing has changed.

Other solutions suggest `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` but as you can see from my screenshots I've tried disabling that with no luck.

If anyone has experience with this your input would be very much welcome...

Comment: It is because the completion you chose actually inserts a snippet, not just plain text, and that snippet determines whether the inserted text is selected or not.  Usually you can just hit `tab` to complete the snippet and it will deselect what you just typed.

Comment: @Mark I'm afraid that's not it. Hitting `tab` doesn't influence the behavior here. I still end up with highlighted text that I have to `escape` to deselect and start typing.

Comment: Hit tab again after accepting the suggestion (and making any changes to that inserted text, if any).